# Redirect the main page after user interact with the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script embedded in to iframe. This is what I am trying to achieve, when the user interact with the iframe, it should send signal to the main page and then redirect it after let say 3 seconds.

I tried many approaches but none of them work.

Comment: show us what you've tried.

Comment: i tried the  window.location.href =

Comment: and this code $(document).ready(function() {
    $("iframe").each(function() {
        var iframe = $(this);
        var pos = iframe.position();
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var s = div.style;
        s.position = "absolute";
        s.left = pos.left + "px";
        s.top = pos.top + "px";
        s.height = iframe.height() + "px";
        s.width = iframe.width() + "px";
        iframe.parent().append(div);
        $(div).data("src", iframe.attr("src")).click(function() {
            window.location = $(this).data("src");
        });
    });
});

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to define a click event on your iframe then use the js function:

```
 window.setTimeout(function(){

        window.location.href = "your_new_page";

    }, 3000);
```

Comment: yes i tried but it's just redirect the page after 3 second without action from user end.

Comment: <iframe scrolling="no" src="https://youwebsite.com" style="border: 0px none; height: 420px; width: 550px">
</iframe>

Comment: i also tried this and add an id to the iframe without result:  $('#iframe').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function () { location.href='http://url.tld'; }, 5000);
    $(this).unbind();
});